# Rails 4: Model Logic - Counting Items by a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

One quick question:

Lets assume I have an User (Devise) & Item Model. The current_user can create and mark his items. If he does, the value of `is_marked` changes to `true`.
That works.
But how can I receive the number of marked Items by the `current_user`?

I thought something like this:

```
current_user.joins(:items).where(user.id: current_user.id)
# How can I count the number of items marked?
# In addition, I don't know if it is the right solution to use joins. Correct me if I am wrong.
```

Associations:
User: `has_many :items`
Item: `belongs_to :user`

Thanks in advance for any answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: Do you have associations  beetwen these models?

Comment: `current_user.items.where(is_marked: true).count`

Comment: @Bartek Gładys Edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have associations between users and items ? If yes, you can simply:

```
current_user.items.where(is_marked: true).count
```

Comment: Works, perfectly. I'll accept it as soon as possible :)

Comment: You can also create a scope on items and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Barket Gladys' answer, you may find it useful to create a scope on items and use that.

In items.rb model file:

```
scope :marked, -> { where(:is_marked => true) }
```

Then use the scope as follows:

```
current_user.items.marked.count
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! That's what I will definitely do at the end :)